# Query the fixed-length period satisfying some condition in mongodb base on daily data

Tags: mongodb

What I'm trying to do is to generate a list of countries that have achieved 2 consecutive weeks of 0 new cases after recording more than 50 cases accumulated.

For example, some country has have achieved 2 consecutive weeks of 0 new cases recorded and before that it has more than 50 accumulated cases.

Is it possible to query the fixed-length period satisfying some condition in mongodb?

***the totalNewCases is the sum of the daily data for each week, not accumulated weekly results.***

**Data After grouping:**

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 0
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 1
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 2
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 3
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 4
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 5
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 6
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 7
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 0.0
},

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 8
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 1.0
},

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 9
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 3.0
},

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 10
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 6.0
},

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 11
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 14.0
},

/* 13 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 12
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 82.0
},

/* 14 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "groupByCountry" : "Afghanistan",
        "groupByWeek" : 13
    },
    "totalNewCases" : 164.0
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can use

$gte , $lte ,$gt , $lt operator for check this condition in  mongoDB

```
db.collectionname.find({totalNewCases:{$gte:5}});
```

Comparison Query Operators

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/